# How to insert datas from a table to another table?

Tags: sql, mysql

USER and USER_1

I want to insert datas from USER_1 to USER.

How to do it ?

I try to do it, but without success :

> INSERT INTO USER WHERE id IN (SELECT *
>   FROM USER_1)

Comment: do the tables have the same schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are sure the schemas are the same...

Use:

```
INSERT INTO USER
SELECT * FROM USER_1
```

This is the Syntax for SQL Server, not sure if it is identical in MySQL.

Comment: I would +1 this but I think you shouldn't assume that the tables have the same schema ;]

Comment: Good point!  You could always:
DROP TABLE USER_1
SELECT *
INTO USER_1
FROM User

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this

```
 INSERT INTO USER 
               (Here is your columns)
         VALUES
               (SELECT * FROM USER_1)
```